# Exceed quota limits when fine tuning (Vertex ai)

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm facing an error while fine-tuning with a custom dataset on Vertex AI from the Google Cloud Platform (GCP). Here's the error message I encountered:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egslj.png)
I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you!

Fine tuned model that i can use.

Comment: I have the same error. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've hit this quota for TPUv3s in `europe-west4`. https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/quotas#custom-trained_model_quotas

You can request an increase in this quota for your model. https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota_detail/view_manage#requesting_higher_quota